# I don't understand an answer. Should I add a comment, or post a new question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I recently (today) asked a question that received what seems to be a clear, concise answer, but one that's beyond my ability to understand (I'm at the cut-and-paste stage with JavaScript, and the answer seems to assume more knowledge than I actually have).

Is it considered better to ask follow-up questions as comments to the answer given, or should I post "fresh" questions to Stack to help me understand the answer that's been given?

Comment: At last go for bounty...:)

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - A bounty will not help without more context from the OP. Yes, the question will get more eyeballs, but if it is not edited, there is no guarantee that the answers given in an effort to win the bounty will do better than the answer already given.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Not to mention that this situation usually occurs with newbie programmers, the likes of which generally don't have the reputation required to be able to post bounties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need clarification on the answer, you should post this as a comment - the person answering is not required to expand and explain the answer, but it is very possible that they will, or will point you to a resource that will help with understanding the answer.

When posting such a comment, explain exactly what you are not understanding and what you are having difficulties with, so a constructive follow-up can be made.

If, after all this you are still in the dark, by all means post a new question, linking to the original and explain in detail what you don't understand and where you are having difficulties.